# Um Bom Gerador de Números Aleatórios Fortran

Tags: números-aleatórios, fortran

O GNA do FORTRAN (rand()) parece ser ruim, isto porque ele é se mostrou pior do que geradores de números aleatórios muito simples. Por exemplo, nas minhas simulações o GNA abaixo

```
SUBROUTINE GNA(iiseed)
USE Variaveis
parameter (ia=843314861,ib=453816693,m=1073741824, r231=1./2147483648.)
INTEGER :: iiseed

iiseed = ib + ia*iiseed
if (iiseed.lt.0) iiseed = (iiseed+m) + m
RndNum = iiseed*r231

END SUBROUTINE GNA
```

se mostrou melhor que o rand() do FORTRAN, e este GNA é bem simples. Alguém saberia me indicar um bom gerador de números aleatórios (GNA) em FORTRAN. Algo que combine eficiência de tempo computacional e aleatoriedade dos números gerados.

Comment: o `rand()` é fracote. Experimenta usar o `RANDOM_NUMBER(x)`...

Comment: Fonte do gerador de números aleatórios:  lilith.fisica.ufmg.br/~dickman/transfers/comp/Notas/rng.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Existem vários algoritmos para geração de números [pseudo aleatórios](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerador_de_n%C3%BAmeros_pseudoaleat%C3%B3rios) e a escolha do algoritmo ideal depende muito do objetivo para o qual os números serão gerados.

O algoritmo mais utilizado atualmente é o [Mersenne Twister - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) que, segundo o artigo, apresenta entre outras vantagens, um período longo (`2^19937 − 1`), portanto a "aleatoriedade" dos números é melhor.

Caso você prefira um algoritmo mais rápido, pode utilizar o [Xorshift - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) (os exemplos de implementação estão em linguagem C), ou alguma das suas variações.

Uma outra opção a ser utilizada, é obter previamente uma lista de números aleatórios em um serviço como, por exemplo, o [Random.ORG](https://www.random.org/) e utilizar esses números no seu programa, lendo-os a partir de um arquivo.

Existem outros serviços como Random.org (e outros algoritmos também), que você pode consultar na [Wikipedia - Lista de Geradores de Números Aleatórios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators).

Seguem alguns sites (em inglês) que já disponibilizam o código-fonte de PRNGs em FORTRAN:

[Alan Miller's Fortran Software](http://jblevins.org/mirror/amiller/#random)

[Multiple stream Mersenne Twister PRNG](http://theo.phys.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~ishikawa/PRNG/mt_stream_en.html)

[Mersenne Twister Home Page](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/FORTRAN/fortran.html)

[Source Codes in Fortran90 e F90_RANDOM](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/f90_random/f90_random.html)

[Random number generation](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucakarc/work/randgen.html)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem? Então, eu uso o Marsaglia. Ele possui um período muito grande e o tempo de execução bem pequeno. Já fizeram muitos testes com ele em relação a correlações e ele está dentro do aceitável. Para utilizado, no seu programa ou rotina que vai utiliza-lo, baste coloca no cabeçalho USE random_utilities e, antes de começar, chame a subrotina CALL initrandom(i,it). Se você precisar de usar um mesmo seed para comparação, pode chamar o rmarin(ij, kl) onde 0 <= IJ <= 31328 & 0 <= KL <= 30081.

```
MODULE varitype1
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I4B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: k15 = SELECTED_INT_KIND(15)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0D0)
END MODULE
MODULE raset
    USE varitype1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP) :: U(1:97), cc, cd, cm
    INTEGER(k15) ::  i97, j97 
END MODULE
MODULE random_utilities
    USE varitype1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(I4B) :: rand_inst = 0
    INTEGER(I4B) :: rand_feedback = 1

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE initrandom(i,i2)
    USE varitype1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(k15),OPTIONAL,INTENT(IN) :: i,i2
    INTEGER(k15) :: seed_in,kl,ij
    CHARACTER(LEN=10) :: fred
    REAL(DP) :: klr

    IF (PRESENT(i)) THEN
        seed_in = i
    ELSE
        seed_in = -1
    END IF
    IF (seed_in /= -1) THEN
        IF (PRESENT(i2)) THEN
            kl = i2
            IF (i2 > 30081) STOP 'i2 > 30081'
        ELSE
            kl = 9373
        END IF
            ij = i
    ELSE
        CALL system_clock(count=ij)
        ij = MOD(ij+rand_inst*100,31328)
        CALL date_and_time(time = fred)
        READ (fred,'(e10.3)') klr
        kl = MOD(INT(klr*1000),30081)
    END IF
        CALL rmarin(ij,kl)
END SUBROUTINE initrandom

REAL(DP) FUNCTION random_real(a,b)
    USE varitype1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: a,b

    random_real = (b-a)*ranmar() + a

END FUNCTION random_real

INTEGER(I4B) FUNCTION random_integer(o1,o2)
    USE varitype1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(I4B), INTENT(IN) :: o1,o2

    random_integer = INT(o2*ranmar()) + o1

END FUNCTION random_integer

SUBROUTINE rmarin(ij, kl)
    !                           0 <= IJ <= 31328
    !                           0 <= KL <= 30081
    USE varitype1
    USE raset
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(k15), INTENT(IN) :: ij, kl
    INTEGER(K15) :: i, j, k, l, ii, jj, m
    REAL(DP) :: s, t

    IF( ij < 0  .OR.  ij > 31328  .OR. kl < 0  .OR.  kl > 30081 ) THEN
      WRITE(*, '(A)') ' The first random number seed must have a value ',  &
                   'between 0 AND 31328'
      WRITE(*, '(A)') ' The second seed must have a value between 0 and 30081'
      STOP
    END IF

    i = MOD(ij/177, 177) + 2
    j = MOD(ij, 177) + 2
    k = MOD(kl/169, 178) + 1
    l = MOD(kl, 169)
    DO ii = 1, 97
      s = 0.0D0
      t = 0.5D0
      DO jj = 1, 24
        m = MOD(MOD(i*j, 179)*k, 179)
        i = j
        j = k
        k = m
        l = MOD(53*l + 1, 169)
        IF (MOD(l*m, 64) >= 32) THEN
          s = s + t
        END IF
        t = 0.5D0*t
      END DO
      u(ii) = s
    END DO
    cc = 362436.0D0/16777216.0D0
    cd = 7654321.0D0/16777216.0D0
    cm = 16777213.0D0/16777216.0D0
    i97 = 97
    j97 = 33

    RETURN
END SUBROUTINE rmarin

FUNCTION ranmar() RESULT(fn_val)
    USE varitype1
    USE raset
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP) :: fn_val
    ! Local variable
    REAL(DP) :: uni

    uni = u(i97) - u(j97)
    IF( uni < 0.0D0 ) uni = uni + 1.0D0
    u(i97) = uni
    i97 = i97 - 1
    IF(i97 == 0) i97 = 97
    j97 = j97 - 1
    IF(j97 == 0) j97 = 97
    cc = cc - cd
    IF( cc < 0.0D0 ) cc = cc + cm
    uni = uni - cc
    IF( uni < 0.0D0 ) uni = uni + 1.0D0
    !IF( uni == 0.0D0 ) uni = 2.0D-38
    fn_val = uni

  RETURN
END FUNCTION ranmar

END MODULE random_utilities
```